# EnumHelper.Parse in LINQ JOIN Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am sorry if it is duplicate question and if it please point me to it.

I am trying to execute below LINQ query and getting below exception. Can anybody tell me how I can solve this

```
IEnumerable<ValueObjects.IR.IRTransactionGroupLink> codeSetsVOs = 
from itc in adjustmentContext.InformationRequestTransactionCodes
join itg in adjustmentContext.InformationRequestTransactionGroups
on itc.InformationRequestTransactionGroup equals itg.Group 
where itc.InformationRequestType == informationRequestType 
select new ValueObjects.IR.IRTransactionGroupLink 
{
IRTransactionGroupType = EnumHelper.Parse<IRTransactionGroupTypeEnum>(itg.Group.Trim(), true),
CountryCode = itc.CountryCode,
Description = itg.Description,
AppliesToAllCountries = itc.CountryCode.Equals("XX") ? true : false
};
```

The exception is

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'HL.Utility.Adjustment.InformationRequest.IRTransactionGroupTypeEnum Parse[IRTransactionGroupTypeEnum](System.String, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression**

Comment: so, entity framework doesn't know how to translate enum.parse into sql, so you'll need to do that after the query has executed.

Comment: @Dareen Kopp... I saw few posts and they also say the same, Can you please tell me how to do this "you'll need to do that after the query has executed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a limitation of LINQ to Entitis, that it can't translate arbitrary C# code to SQL. You can workaround this by leaving  `IRTransactionGroupType` empty in your initial query (that is to be translated into SQL and executed in database server), then you can set actual value of the property in client after server query executed, for example :

```
IEnumerable<ValueObjects.IR.IRTransactionGroupLink> query = 
                from itc in adjustmentContext.InformationRequestTransactionCodes
                join itg in adjustmentContext.InformationRequestTransactionGroups
                on itc.InformationRequestTransactionGroup equals itg.Group 
                where itc.InformationRequestType == informationRequestType 
                select new
                {
                    GroupType = itg.Group,
                    CountryCode = itc.CountryCode,
                    Description = itg.Description,
                    AppliesToAllCountries = itc.CountryCode.Equals("XX") ? true : false
                };
var serverQueryResult = query.ToList();
var clientQuery = from r in serverQueryResult
                  select new ValueObjects.IR.IRTransactionGroupLink 
                  {
                      IRTransactionGroupType = EnumHelper.Parse<IRTransactionGroupTypeEnum>(r.Group.Trim(), true),
                      CountryCode = r.CountryCode,
                      Description = r.Description,
                      AppliesToAllCountries = r.AppliesToAllCountries
                  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much har07. Even though we are not using this process I marked it answer because I tested it and it works and gives me what I want. We use this LINQ query on data access layer. So I created IRTransactionGroupLink POCO class that has IRTransactionGroupType  as string. We have an EntityMapper that converts POCO objects into Value Objects so I was able to convert IRTransactionGroupLink POCO into IRTransactionGroupLink ValueObject and it automatically assigns IRTransactionGroupType  enum in ValueObjects after reading IRTransactionGroupType  string value from Entity.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query to below

```
 IEnumerable<Entities.InformationRequestTransactionGroupLink> irTransactionGroupLinksEntities = 
(from itc in
this.adjustmentContext.InformationRequestTransactionCodes
join itg in this.adjustmentContext.InformationRequestTransactionGroups
on itc.InformationRequestTransactionGroup equals itg.Group
where itc.InformationRequestType == informationRequestType
select new
{
 sInformationRequestTransactionGroupType = itg.Group.Trim(),
 sCountryCode = itc.CountryCode,
 sDescription = itg.Description,
 sAppliesToAllCountries = itc.CountryCode.Trim().Equals("XX") ? true : false}).AsEnumerable()
.Select(irtgLink => new Entities.InformationRequestTransactionGroupLink
{
 InformationRequestTransactionGroupType = irtgLink.sInformationRequestTransactionGroupType,
 CountryCode = irtgLink.sCountryCode,
 Description = irtgLink.sDescription,
 AppliesToAllCountries = irtgLink.sCountryCode.Trim().Equals("XX") ? true : false
});
```